# How to style the option of an HTML select element?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Here's my HTML:

```html
  <select id="ddlProducts" name="ddProducts"> 
      <option>Product1 : Electronics </option>
      <option>Product2 : Sports </option>
  </select>
```

I want to make the name of the product (i.e. 'Product1', 'Product2' , etc) bold, and its categories(viz. Electronics, Sports, etc) italicized, using CSS only. I found an old question that mentioned it's not possible using HTML and CSS, but hopefully, there's a solution now.

Comment: options are still just as annoying to style as they have ever been. what you may want to use is an optgroup: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/optgroup.html

this will give you a bold and italicized category (like Electronics) under which a bunch of options fall.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

There are only a few style attributes that can be applied to an `<option>` element.

This is because this type of element is an example of a "replaced element". They are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via CSS.

There are replacement plug-ins/libraries that look like a `<select>` but are actually composed of regular HTML elements that **CAN** be styled.

Comment: This behaviour varies across different browsers and different OSes; it's worth clarifying if you're talking mainly about IE on Windows.

Comment: You can style `select > option`, but there are no reliable crossbrowser solution for doing so and, on chrome at least you can at most customize font size, family, background and foreground color.
Maybe some more tweaks, but things as padding, hover color and such I couldn't succeed on changing.
Indeed there might be alternatives, but depending on the project the <select> tag might be necessary for example for angular validation or some other reason.

Comment: @none I have posted an answer to [Styling option tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500108/styling-option-tags/36434673).  It does not show how to style `<option>`, but it does show how to emulate `<select>` so you can style the options.

Comment: In the introduction of mobile devices, this is even less styleable, as the options elements are not even displayed in relation to the select in the page flow - it is listed in a separate scrollable section at the bottom of the screen - styled very differently than how you expect in a traditional browser.

Comment: Cannot be styled for sure (only minor things to options). Please take a look at this how-to from the guys at w3schools to completely customize it with only JS: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp so you can

Comment: @Jimmery this doesn't seem to work on Chrome? Are you sure this works? Thanks!

Comment: @Diodeus - James MacFarlane 

If what you are saying is true, then why do i get a different style combobox on same OS (macos) but different browsers (check screenshot below)? https://share.getcloudapp.com/NQurWNRx (Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83)

https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuZAvgN (firefox version 80.0)

Answer (score 133):

No, it's not possible, as the styling for these elements is handled by the user's OS. [MSDN will answer your question here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528070441/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Except for `background-color` and `color`, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored.

Comment: so the conclusion is : "a select's option cannot be partially styled just with CSS", right??? :(

Comment: The important point here is that they *can* be styled, only very minimally.

Comment: To add to devios's point -- the native select can be minimally styled for Windows, but not necessarily for other OSes. As pumbo mentions below, you'll need to swap out the select for other elements (usually an ul) and duplicate select functionality in JavaScript for full control over styles.

Comment: <option style="color: 'red';"> doesn't works for me... suggestion?

Comment: `style="background-color: red;color: red;"` does not work for me.
EDIT: After closing the developer console the style was applied.

Comment: ***Update:*** "You'll notice that the options don't inherit the font set on the parent. You also can't consistently set things like spacing and colors. For example, Firefox will apply color and background-color when set on the <option> elements, Chrome won't. Neither of them will apply any kind of spacing (e.g. padding)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling <- More info here and here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 53):

You can style the option elements to some extent.

Using the `*` CSS selector you can style the options inside the box that is drawn by the system.

Example:

```
#ddlProducts *
{
 border-radius: 15px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

That will look like this:

[image]

Comment: That is true only because the all selector targets the shadow DOM innards, you can target those manually per browser.

Comment: This is not true, even If you use  * you can just style the background and color.

Comment: @Goutham Harshith Hence the wording "to some extent".

Answer (score 27):

I found and using this good example of styling the selects and options.You can do with this select all you want.Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/47/)

```js
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function() {

  // Cache the number of options
  var $this = $(this),
    numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  // Hides the select element
  $this.addClass('s-hidden');

  // Wrap the select element in a div
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

  // Cache the styled div
  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

  // Show the first select option in the styled div
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  // Cache the list items
  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
  $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
  // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
  $listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
  $(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.s-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font: normal 11px/22px Arial, Sans-Serif;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.styledSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.styledSelect:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 6px;
}

.styledSelect:active,
.styledSelect.active {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.options li {
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.options li:hover {
  background-color: #39f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox1">
  <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
  <option value="aye">Aye</option>
  <option value="eh">Eh</option>
  <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
  <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
</select>
<select id="selectbox2">
  <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
  <option value="january">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="june">June</option>
  <option value="july">July</option>
  <option value="august">August</option>
  <option value="september">September</option>
  <option value="october">October</option>
  <option value="november">November</option>
  <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you please post the code here because maybe some day it will be removed but here it will be stay in the save place

Comment: It is very dynamic way of doing what you want with the select, if you will have a better option i will be happy to see it as an answer here @ahnbizcad

Comment: **This is NOT a native html <select>** it just re-renders one with some jQuery code. If your gonna do this might as well use a jQuery plugin, React component etc. that handles keyboard UP/DOWN, typeahead/searching etc.

Comment: Wow. What a lot of work to compensate for the wrong decision to make the OS responsible for Option elements, even if it works.

Comment: This does not work. The options still have their default style.

Answer (score 17):

Here's some ways to style `<option>` along with the `<select>` if you're using Bootstrap and/or jquery. I understand this isn't what the original poster is asking but I thought I could help others that stumble onto this question.

You can still achieve the goal of styling each `<option>` separately, but may need to apply some style to the `<select>` as well. My favorite is the "Bootstrap Select" library mentioned below.

---

## Bootstrap Select Library (jquery)

If you're already using bootstrap, you can try the **[Bootstrap Select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) library** or the library below (since it has a bootstrap theme).

Note that you are able to style the entire `select` element, or the `option` elements separately.

*Examples*:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Dependencies*: requires **jQuery** v1.9.1+, **Bootstrap**, Bootstrap’s dropdown.js component, and Bootstrap's CSS

*Compatibility*: Unsure, but bootstrap says it "supports the latest, stable releases of all major browsers and platforms"

*Demo*: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

```css
.special {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #bc0000 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option class="special">Ketchup</option>
  <option style="background: #5cb85c; color: #fff;">Relish</option>
</select>
```

---

## Select2 (JS lib)

There's a library you can use called **[Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)**.

[image: select2]

*Dependencies*: Library is JS + CSS + HTML only (does not require JQuery).

*Compatibility*: IE 8+, Chrome 8+, Firefox 10+, Safari 3+, Opera 10.6+

*Demo*: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

There's also a [bootstrap theme](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme) available.

No Bootstrap example:

```js
$(function() {
  var $select = $('.select2');
  
  $select.select2({
    theme: 'paper'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="select2 form-control" placeholder="Country">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Bootstrap example:

```js
$(function() {
  var $select = $('.select2');
  
  $select.select2({
    theme: 'paper'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.2/paper/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="select2 form-control" placeholder="Country">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

## MDBootstrap ($ & Bootstrap & JQuery)

If you have extra money, you can use a premium library [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/select/). (This is an *entire UI Kit*, so it's not light)

This allows you to style your select and option elements using the [Material design](https://material.io/design/).

[image]

There is a free version, but it won't allow you to use the pretty Material design!

*Dependencies*: *Bootstrap 4*, JQuery,

*Compatibility*: ["supports the latest, stable releases of all major browsers and platforms."](https://mdbootstrap.com/general/browsers-and-devices/)

*Demo*: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/select/#color

Comment: Because the question is about styling the **option** element, not the **select** element.

Comment: This answer is misleading, because while you explicitly show that you can style the *select*, you claim that the *option* is what can be styled, even though it's an OS element that only accepts minimal CSS styling at all.

Comment: @Jsalinas sorry, my previous answer was atrocious. I've replaced it with one that I hope is better.

Comment: Select2 4.0 isn't pure anymore as it now builds upon jQuery.

Answer (score 16):

Seems like I can just set the CSS for the `select` in Chrome or Firefox directly.  CSS and HTML code provided below :

```css
.boldoption {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Some normal-font option</option>
    <option>Another normal-font option</option>
    <option class="boldoption">Some bold option</option>
</select>
```

[image: Working Code on Chrome]

[image: Working Code on Firefox]

[image: Working Code on Firefox 93]

Comment: @Muhamed Al Khalil: I updated the example to be more clear, since the currently selected option has its own style, too.  If that doesn't work, I suspect browser compatibility issues, then. =\

Comment: @Akash: Interesting, this worked on Firefox before they released Firefox Quantum, and it still currently works on Chrome (60%+ of users).  I bet it's a bug!

Comment: This only works for the drop down, not what is displayed as selected. Too Bad.

Comment: @WebDude0482 if you want what's displayed as selected to be bold too you can do `select, option:checked { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: only work in chromium/chrome and not in firefox and all text is bold, we can't mix '**bold** - non-bold' text

Comment: @bcag2: It works fine in FF, just posted an image.  And OP was asking how to style an entire option, not enough space to really break out every edge-case.  Cheers.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger: not in my updated FF version 93.0 under Ubuntu (I use dark theme)!

Comment: @bcag2: Your theme may be broken.  Also, not sure why "updating" FF would cause this break.  Just did an update, still works perfectly fine, attached yet another image.  Thanks again for adding your insight.  Cheers.

Comment: Not visible in Chrome on OSX in 2022

Comment: doesnt work on android

Answer (score 7):

Some properties can be styled for`<option>` tag:

- `font-family`
- `color`
- `font-*`
- `background-color`

Also you can use custom font for individual `<option>` tag, for example any [google font](https://fonts.google.com/), [Material Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/) or other icon fonts from [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) or alike. (That may come handy for font selectors etc.)

Considering that, you can create font-family stack and insert icons in `<option>` tags, eg.

```
    <select>
        <option style="font-family: 'Icons', 'Roboto', sans-serif;">a    ★★★</option>
        <option style="font-family: 'Icons', 'Roboto', sans-serif;">b    ★★★★</option>
    </select>
```

where `★` is taken from `Icons` and the rest is from `Roboto`.

Note though that custom fonts do not work for mobile select.

Comment: <option style="color: 'red';"> doesn't works for me... suggestion?

Comment: Remove quotes over `red`:  
<option style="color: red;">

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, the only way is to use a plugin that replaces `<select>` functionality.

A list of jQuery plugins: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/select/

Take a look at the example using `Select2` plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/swsLokfj/23/

Comment: In current jQuery Select2 4.x, the way to do this is now different. See: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30948247), [docs](https://select2.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can add :before and :after and style those. At least it's something

```css
option {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

option:before {
  content: ">";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

option:hover:before {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<select id="ddlProducts" name="ddProducts">
  <option>Product1 : Electronics </option>
  <option>Product2 : Sports </option>
</select>
```

Comment: yup only font-size

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap allows you to use styling via data-content:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>Relish</span>">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Example:
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: HTML embedded in data attributes makes me feel really icky.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there aren't much properties to change, but you can achieve following style only with css:

[image]

```css
.options {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 10px;
}

select {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <select>
    <option value="">Apple</option>
    <option value="">Banana</option>
    <option value="">Orange</option>
    <option value="">Mango</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what youre looking for? I did it with jQuery!

Run Code Snippet

```js
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
        id      = $(this).attr("id"),
        name    = $(this).attr("name");
    var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
    template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
    template += '<div class="custom-options">';
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
    });
    template += '</div></div>';

    $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).after(template);
});
$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $('html').one('click',function() {
        $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    });
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
    $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
    $(this).addClass("selection");
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

 .custom-select-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .custom-select-wrapper select {
        display: none;
    }
    .custom-select {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .custom-select-trigger {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 170px;
        padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #5f5f5f;
        line-height: 50px;
        background: #EAEAEA;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left:20px;
        border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .custom-select-trigger:hover {
        background-color: #d9d9d9;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .custom-select-trigger:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        top: 50%; right: 25px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
        border-right: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
    }
    .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
        margin-top: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
    }
    .custom-options {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
        margin: 15px 0;
        border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
        background: #fff;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        margin-left: 20px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        pointer-events: none;
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
    .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        pointer-events: all;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    .custom-options:before {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
        width: 7px; height: 7px;
        margin-bottom: -4px;
        border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        background: #fff;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .option-hover:before {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .custom-option {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 22px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #b5b5b5;
        line-height: 47px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-option:first-of-type {
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .custom-option:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    .custom-option:hover,
    .custom-option.selection {
        background: #f2f0f0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="My Categories">
    <option value="categoryOne">Category 1</option>
    <option value="categoryTwo">Category 2</option>
    <option value="categoryThree">Category 3</option>
    <option value="categoryFour">Category 4</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What is the value of the default option.

Comment: @KadenSkinner it's the placeholder

Answer (score 2):

It's will definitely work.
The select option is rendered by **OS** not by html. That's whythe CSS style doesn't effect,.. generally 
`option{font-size : value ;
 background-color:colorCode; 
 border-radius:value; }`
this will work, but we can't customize the padding, margin etc..

Below code 100% work to customize select tag taken from [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: this code is straight from w2schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Answer (score 1):

It's 2017 and it IS possible to target specific select options. In my project I have a table with a **class="variations"**, and the select options are in the table cell **td="value"**, and the select has an ID **select#pa_color**.
The option element also has a class **option="attached"** (among other class tags).
If a user is logged in as a wholesale customer, they can see all of the color options. But retail customers are not allowed to purchase 2 color options, so I've disabled them

```
<option class="attached" disabled>color 1</option>
<option class="attached" disabled>color 2</option>
```

It took a little logic, but here is how I targeted the disabled select options.

**CSS**

```
table.variations td.value select#pa_color option.attached:disabled {
display: none !important;
}
```

With that, my color options are only visible to wholesale customers.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving here a quick alternative, using class toggle on a table. The behavior is very similar than a select, but can be styled with transition, filters and colors, each children individually.

```js
function toggleSelect(){ 
 if (store.classList[0] === "hidden"){
    store.classList = "viewfull"
  }
  else {
    store.classList = "hidden"
  }
}
```

```css
#store {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 110px;
  max-width: 50%
 }
 
.hidden {
  display: none
 }
 
.viewfull {
  display: block
}

#store :nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lime;
}

span {font-size:2rem;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<span onclick="toggleSelect()">⮋</span>
 <div id="store" class="hidden">
 
<ul><li><a href="#keylogger">keylogger</a></li><li><a href="#1526269343113">1526269343113</a></li><li><a href="#slow">slow</a></li><li><a href="#slow2">slow2</a></li><li><a href="#Benchmark">Benchmark</a></li><li><a href="#modal">modal</a></li><li><a href="#buma">buma</a></li><li><a href="#1526099371108">1526099371108</a></li><a href="#1526099371108o">1526099371108o</a></li><li><a href="#pwnClrB">pwnClrB</a></li><li><a href="#stars%20u">stars%20u</a></li><li><a href="#pwnClrC">pwnClrC</a></li><li><a href="#stars ">stars </a></li><li><a href="#wello">wello</a></li><li><a href="#equalizer">equalizer</a></li><li><a href="#pwnClrA">pwnClrA</a></li></ul>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you mean [element]`.classList.add(name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styles to add custome styling to `<option>` tags.

For eg : `<option style="font-weight:bold;color:#09C;">Option 1</option>`
This will apply the styles to this particular `<option>` element only.

Then you can use a bit of javascript magic to apply the inline styles to all of the `<option>` elements within a `<select>` tag like so :

`var select = $(document).getElementById('#select-element-id')`

`var option = select.children('#option-element-id')`

`option.css('font-weight', 'bold')`

`option.css('font-size', '24px')`

You can also use `<option value="" disabled> <br> </option>` to add a line-break between the options.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(() => {
        const optionValues = document.querySelectorAll(".search-form__value");
        const searchOptions = document.querySelector(".search-form__selector");
        const dropdown = document.querySelector(".search-form__dropdown");
        const input = document.getElementById("search-form-loc");
        const selectorText = document.querySelector(".search-form__label--loc");

        searchOptions.addEventListener("click", function () {
          dropdownHandler();
        });

        optionValues.forEach((option) => {
          option.addEventListener("click", function () {
            updateUI(input, selectorText, this);
          });
        });

        window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
          if (event.target != dropdown) {
            dropdown.classList.remove("search-form__dropdown--show");
          }
        });

        function dropdownHandler() {
          dropdown.classList.toggle("search-form__dropdown--show");
        }

        function updateUI(input, selectorText, referedThis) {
          input.value = referedThis.textContent.trim();
          selectorText.textContent = referedThis.textContent.trim();
          dropdown.classList.remove("search-form__dropdown--show");
        }
      })();
```

```css
/* CSS Reset Starts */

  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    font-family:  sans-serif;
    color: #777;
    background-color: slateblue !important;
  }
  /* CSS Reset Ends */

  .search-form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;

    background: #fff;
  }

  .search-form__label {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }

  .search-form__selector {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    background: #fff;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .search-form__line {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #777;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  .search-form__icon {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  /* Dropdown */
  .search-form__dropdown {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 30px -10px #96aa6480;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: max-content;
    transition: 0.4s;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .search-form__value {
    padding: 7px;
  }

  .search-form__value:hover {
    background: #0667d5;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .pos-rel {
    position: relative;
  }

  .search-form__dropdown--show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="hidden" name="search-form-loc" id="search-form-loc" />
      <div class="pos-rel">
        <div class="search-form__selector">
          <p class="search-form__label search-form__label--loc">Select From List</p>
          <div class="search-form__line">&nbsp;</div>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down search-form__icon"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="search-form__dropdown">
          <li class="search-form__value" data-loc="search-form-loc">UK</li>
          <li class="search-form__value" data-loc="search-form-loc">Barcelona</li>
          <li class="search-form__value" data-loc="search-form-loc">Brazil</li>
          <li class="search-form__value" data-loc="search-form-loc">Hungary</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: After a lot of research how to do it in css only yes there are possible ways but more complex so I tried to do it in javascript caring about all the values and things to be sent on server hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add left and right padding to visible option items, which usually have zero padding, you can add one or more non-breaking whitespace characters (&nbsp;) to the left and right of each option item, like this:

`<option value="INTERNAL VALUE">&nbsp;VISIBLE ITEM&nbsp;</option>`

Answer (score 0):

This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be styled via CSS.

```js
 $(function() {
    var clicky;
    var t=0;
    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        clicky = $(e.target);
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        clicky = null;
    });

    $("select").focusout(function(e) {
        if (typeof clicky.attr('id') !== typeof undefined && clicky.attr('id') !== false) {
         $(this).parents().children("span.selected").html(clicky.html());
         $(this).children('option[value="'+clicky.attr('id')+'"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
        
        $(this).parents().children("span.lists").html('');
        

    });
    $('select > option').text(function(i, text) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('selected');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            $(this).parents().parents().children("span.selected").html(text);
    }
 });

  $("select").focusin(function(){
   $(this).children('option').text(function(i, text) {
       $(this).parents().children("span.lists").append("<span class='item' id='"+$(this).attr('value')+"'>"+text+"</span>");
    });
  });

 });
```

```css
select {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance: none;

}
label{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color:#ccc;

}
label .selected{
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
label span.lists{
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #ccc;
 background-color:#fff;
 z-index: 9;
}
label span.item{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="?" method="GET">
 <label><span class="selected">select..</span> <span class="lists"></span>
 <select name="test">
  <option value="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</option>
  <option value="2" selected>item 2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
  <option value="4">item 4</option>
 </select>
 </label><br>
 <label><span class="selected">select..</span> <span class="lists"></span>
 <select name="test2">
  <option value="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</option>
  <option value="2">item 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>item 3</option>
  <option value="4">item 4</option>
 </select>
 </label><br>
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

try this it may help you

```
[ https://codepen.io/venu9l/pen/jeNXzY][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class and gives font-weight:700; in option. But by using this all the text will become bold.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output of below code]

This is a html css code used to style option and select tag.
Selected option : background and bold
After closing , it looks in itlaics.

```
    <style>
        .mydropdown{
         border:none;
         border-bottom:2px dotted black;
         display:inline;max-width:20%;
         font-style: italic;
         font-weight: 600;
         cursor: pointer;  
    }
    .mydropdown:hover , .myoption:active , .myoption:checked{
         border:2px dotted green;
    }
    .myoption{
         font-style: normal;
    }
    .mydropdown .myoption:checked,
    .mydropdown .myoption:hover ,
    .mydropdown .myoption:active {
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 600;
     }
    </style>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using CSS and very tricky!

Actually it's a hack. You have to below 3 things to the select option

- `onfocus="this.size=2;"`
- `onblur="this.size=0;"`
- `onchange="this.size=1;this.blur()"`

HTML code:

```html
<select onfocus="this.size=3;" onblur="this.size=0;" onchange="this.size=1; this.blur()"> 
    <option>Product1 : Electronics </option>
    <option>Product2 : Sports </option>
</select>
```

Thats it! Now you can style css ass usual. if you want use a class and style. here I just show without class
CSS code:

```css
.option: nth-child(1){
  background-color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
.option: nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Corrections: in the HTML code it should be onfocus="this.size=2;" since 2 list elements. anyway if it is static you can directly give the size else handle it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
        id      = $(this).attr("id"),
        name    = $(this).attr("name");
    var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
    template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
    template += '<div class="custom-options">';
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
    });
    template += '</div></div>';

    $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).after(template);
});
$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $('html').one('click',function() {
        $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    });
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
    $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
    $(this).addClass("selection");
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
    $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

 .custom-select-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .custom-select-wrapper select {
        display: none;
    }
    .custom-select {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .custom-select-trigger {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 170px;
        padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #5f5f5f;
        line-height: 50px;
        background: #EAEAEA;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left:20px;
        border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .custom-select-trigger:hover {
        background-color: #d9d9d9;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .custom-select-trigger:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        top: 50%; right: 25px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
        border-right: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
    }
    .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
        margin-top: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
    }
    .custom-options {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
        margin: 15px 0;
        border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
        background: #fff;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        margin-left: 20px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        pointer-events: none;
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
    .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        pointer-events: all;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    .custom-options:before {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
        width: 7px; height: 7px;
        margin-bottom: -4px;
        border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        background: #fff;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .option-hover:before {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .custom-option {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 22px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #b5b5b5;
        line-height: 47px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-option:first-of-type {
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .custom-option:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    .custom-option:hover,
    .custom-option.selection {
        background: #f2f0f0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="My Categories">
    <option value="categoryOne">Category 1</option>
    <option value="categoryTwo">Category 2</option>
    <option value="categoryThree">Category 3</option>
    <option value="categoryFour">Category 4</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to involve JavaScript try this:

```
select {
  margin-top: 2% !important;
  font-size: 19px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  width: 25% !important;
  padding: 6px 12px !important;
}
option {
  min-height: 1.5rem !important;
  padding: 14px !important;
}
```